# Can BackBone JS events call anonymous functions?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

So, let's suppose I have an event listener on a model like so:

```
this.listenTo(anotherModel, 'change:whatever', this.myMethod);
```

What is myMethod is a super simple, one line snippet of code?  I'd like to use an anonymous function in this situation, but I can't seem to do that.

```
this.listenTo(anotherModel, 'change:whatever', function() {
  //The simplest code in the world
});
```

What can I do?  Or is my object doomed to be filled with one-line methods?

Comment: nothing can call anonymous functions except themselves...

Comment: That should be correct and possible. I've used anonymous functions with listenTo before, if I remember correctly.

Comment: That works. If you need `this` to reference the model, either `bind` it or set a variable to `this` and use that variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## yes

Bind anonymous function that doesn't need access to the view instance:

```
this.listenTo(anotherModel, 'change:whatever', function() {
  console.log('whatever changed!');
});
```

Bind anonymous function that does need access to the view instance via ECMAScript's function.bind:

```
this.listenTo(anotherModel, 'change:whatever', function() {
  this.$el.append('whatever changed');
}.bind(this)); //the .bind here is key!
```

...or just pass a 4th argument and Backbone will bind the context for you

```
this.listenTo(anotherModel, 'change:whatever', function() {
  this.$el.append('whatever changed');
}, this); //the this here is key!
```

For what it's worth, technically your run-of-the-mill backbone view "method" is an anonymous function:

```
Backbone.View.extend({someMethod: function() {/*this function is anonymous technically*/}});
```

That's all fine. For consistency I always define my event handler functions as view methods and generally name them clearly:

```
Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {'click .start', 'onClickStart'},
    initialize: function () {
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.onChange);
    },
    onClickStart: function() {/*awesome code here*/},
    onChange: function() {/*more awesome code here*/}
});
```

Note that this helps with testability as well.

Comment: And there's always [`_.bind`](http://underscorejs.org/#bind) if you're not sure you'll have `Function.bind` and don't want to use the fourth argument.

Comment: Yup but the syntax for that starts to get overly involved if the goal with an anonymous function was to have some small code right there, that extra pair of far-apart parens with _.bind(function(){}) is about where I draw the line and just put the function elsewhere, but it works and if the syntax doesn't bother you, go for it.

Comment: That was an excellent and very thorough answer.  I was using that exact syntax and it wasn't working before, but now it is.  Weird...

Another followup question: can you use anonymous functions with the delegated events on the view itself?  So, instead of a view having the events property of `events: {'click': 'myMethod'}`, I could instead somehow use `events: {'click': function(){console.log('whatever!')}}`

Comment: No, you cannot do that. You need strings there that are names of methods on your view instances. The `events` hash is just a convenience/helper construct and it expects method names as strings not actual function objects. Read the source for details, it's straightforward what backbone is doing during `delegateEvents`.

Comment: Oh, I get how that works.  I guess my question was more like is there a convenient way to get around that?  I don't want to mess with delegate events too much, but on the other hand, I don't really think I need 60 methods on my view.